# How to make an array of items which are checked in checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have some 20 `check boxes` ( dynamic number) in a HTML page which is `checked` by default. A user can `uncheck` it or leave it `checked`. At the end, there is a button to `submit`.

How to get the items that are only checked at the time of submitting?

Comment: Can you please post your code?

Comment: `var arr = $('YourCheckBoxSelector').filter(":checked").map(function () { return this.value; }).get(); `

Comment: https://github.com/marioizquierdo/jquery.serializeJSON - This will might help you out for all input types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a plain javascript solution, you can use [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector).

Retrieve the checkboxes and then loop over them, then `push()` all of the ones that have the `checked: true` property to an array called `checked`.

```js
var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]");
var submit = document.getElementById("submit");

function getChecked() {
  var checked = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
    var checkbox = checkboxes[i];
    if (checkbox.checked) checked.push(checkbox.value);
  }

  return checked;
}

submit.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var checked = getChecked();
  console.log(checked);
});
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" value="first" checked>
<input type="checkbox" value="second" checked>
<input type="checkbox" value="third" checked>

<input type="submit" id="submit">
```

Comment: how to it after all necessary checking and un checking ?

Comment: Updated to include a submit button!

Comment: so how to fetch the value attributes only, instead of tag

Comment: Updated to only `.push()` the `checkbox.value` into the `checked` array

Comment: Though the answer is perfectly correct, it'd be more cleaner if we use the javascript the better way. 
1. Get List of checked input fields: `let checkboxes = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]:checked"))`
2. Get array of values: `let values = checkboxes.map(item => item.value)`
I'd encourage you guys to play with these things.

Comment: Provided you don't need to support <IE9, I absolutely agree!

Answer (score 0):

Get all check boxes by `css Class` and iterate to checked the condition `element.checked` on it

Check this code snippet

```js
function checkCheckBoxes(){
$("input.abc").each(function(index, element){
  if(!element.checked){
   console.log(index+" not checked");
  } else{
  console.log(index+" checked");
  }
});
return false;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form action="">
<input type="checkbox"  class="abc"/>
<input type="checkbox"  class="abc"/>
<input type="checkbox"  class="abc"/>
<input type="checkbox"  class="abc"/>
<input type="checkbox"  class="abc"/>
<input type="checkbox"  class="abc"/>
<input type="checkbox"  class="abc"/>
<input type="checkbox"  class="abc"/>
  <input type="submit"  onclick="return checkCheckBoxes()" value="Submit">
</form>
```